# c# adding array calculations to new decimal

Tags: c#, arrays, sum, average

So the issue is that I can't get `total += parkFee` to add all the parkFee's together, it just seems to take 20 the `max_fee` and multiply it by the array length (30) instead of taking parkFee's new sum.

It's most likely something super easy that I'm missing because I'm very new to this but I just can't seem to figure it out.
I feel like the issue might have to do with the `if` statement. If someone could point me in the right direction It'd be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
/*pseudocode
Program : CarParkCalc3
     * HOURLY_RATE=2.50
     * MAX_FREE=20.00
     * int[]hoursArray 
     * parkFee = HOURLY_RATE * hoursArray
     * IF parkTime > MAX_FEE THEN
     *      OUTPUT MAX_FEE
     * ELSE
     *      OUTPUT parkFee
     * ENDIF
*/


const decimal HOURLY_RATE = 2.50m;
const decimal MAX_FEE = 20m;
decimal parkFee = 0;
int[] hoursArray = { 8, 24, 9, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 1, 2, 9, 8, 8, 9, 7, 9, 15, 6, 1, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 1, 2, 9, 8 };


Console.WriteLine("Hours  Park fee");
for (int index = 0; index < hoursArray.Length; index++)

{
    {
        parkFee = HOURLY_RATE * hoursArray[index];

        if (parkFee > MAX_FEE)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,6}   {1,9} ", hoursArray[index], MAX_FEE.ToString("N"));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,6}   {1,9} ", hoursArray[index], parkFee.ToString("N"));
        }

    }

}

decimal total = 0;
double average = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < hoursArray.Length; index++)

{
    total += parkFee;
}

average = (double)total / hoursArray.Length;
Console.WriteLine("Total = " + total);
Console.WriteLine("Average = " + average.ToString("N2"));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You are re-calculating parkFee every time in your upper for loop. The total is just adding the same parkFee (the last calculated value from your upper for loop) for every element in your array

Comment: The best way to solve this, and for you to learn something new, is that you debug this code, watching how are all the variables changing with each line of code. That way you'll see whats wrong with it

Comment: have a look at the last loop where you add up the `parkFee`. Check at each iteration the value of `parkFee`! You can print it to the console if you don't want to or cannot use the debugger. You will see that it does not change! Now the reason for this is your solution

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        {
            /*pseudocode
            Program : CarParkCalc3
                 * HOURLY_RATE=2.50
                 * MAX_FREE=20.00
                 * int[]hoursArray 
                 * parkFee = HOURLY_RATE * hoursArray
                 * IF parkTime > MAX_FEE THEN
                 *      OUTPUT MAX_FEE
                 * ELSE
                 *      OUTPUT parkFee
                 * ENDIF
            */


            const decimal HOURLY_RATE = 2.50m;
            const decimal MAX_FEE = 20m;

            int[] hoursArray = { 8, 24, 9, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 1, 2, 9, 8, 8, 9, 7, 9, 15, 6, 1, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 1, 2, 9, 8 };
            decimal[] parkFee = new decimal[hoursArray.Length];

            Console.WriteLine("Hours  Park fee");
            for (int index = 0; index < hoursArray.Length; index++)

            {



                {
                    parkFee[index] = HOURLY_RATE * hoursArray[index];

                    if (parkFee[index] > MAX_FEE)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0,6}   {1,9} ", hoursArray[index], MAX_FEE.ToString("N"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0,6}   {1,9} ", hoursArray[index], parkFee[index].ToString("N"));
                    }

                }

            }

            decimal total = 0;
            double average = 0;
            for (int index = 0; index < hoursArray.Length; index++)

            {
                total += parkFee[index];
            }

            average = (double)total / hoursArray.Length;
            Console.WriteLine("Total = " + total);
            Console.WriteLine("Average = " + average.ToString("N2"));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

}

You can do this with array were only using one variable that's why you were getting single value

Comment: Looking at the posted question and the comments is becomes quite apparent the OP is trying to learn. This answer has the educational value of -1. There is no explanation whatsoever. Handing over fishes without even an attempt to teach fishing is not of great value or use IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Just move total += parkFee; to the upper loop.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*pseudocode
        Program : CarParkCalc3
             * HOURLY_RATE=2.50
             * MAX_FREE=20.00
             * int[]hoursArray 
             * parkFee = HOURLY_RATE * hoursArray
             * IF parkTime > MAX_FEE THEN
             *      OUTPUT MAX_FEE
             * ELSE
             *      OUTPUT parkFee
             * ENDIF
        */


            const decimal HOURLY_RATE = 2.50m;
            const decimal MAX_FEE = 20m;
            decimal parkFee = 0;
            int[] hoursArray = { 8, 24, 9, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 1, 2, 9, 8, 8, 9, 7, 9, 15, 6, 1, 7, 6, 12, 10, 11, 23, 1, 2, 9, 8 };
            decimal total = 0;
            double average = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Hours  Park fee");
            for (int index = 0; index < hoursArray.Length; index++)
            {



                {
                    parkFee = HOURLY_RATE * hoursArray[index];
                    total += parkFee;
                    if (parkFee > MAX_FEE)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0,6}   {1,9} ", hoursArray[index], MAX_FEE.ToString("N"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0,6}   {1,9} ", hoursArray[index], parkFee.ToString("N"));
                    }

                }

            }




            average = (double)total / hoursArray.Length;
            Console.WriteLine("Total = " + total);
            Console.WriteLine("Average = " + average.ToString("N2"));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```